# Placing labels "around" a GraphicsGrid

Tags: graphics, labeling

I have the following code, which produce the image shown.

```
Labeled[GraphicsGrid[{{Fig1A, Fig1B, Fig1C}, {Fig1D, Fig1E, Fig1F}, {Fig1G, Fig1H, Fig1I}}, Spacings -> {0, 0}, Frame -> None, AspectRatio -> 1], {Pane["Too far out, and I need a label (centered) for each row"],"Fine!" , "This is fine, except I need a label (centered) for each column"}, \{Left, Bottom, Top}, RotateLabel -> True, LabelStyle -> [![enter image description here][1]][1]Directive[Bold, FontFamily -> "Consolas", FontSize -> 16]]
```

The problem (as also summarized in the current labels) is that:

**A)** There is too much white-space between the chart and the label on the left.

**B)** I need more than an overarching label at the left and on top. I need centered labels for each row on the left, and centered lablles for each column at the top.

So, overall, I am looking to produce a nice and compact image.

How can I achieve my goal?

**UPDATE:**
I thought setting Spacings -> {-100, 0} worked, but that also makes the plot overlap...

[image]

Comment: Look in my questions, I wonder if you can adapt the frame margins one for this?

Comment: @CATrevillian Could you please provide me the link?

Comment: Find the relevant answer to the question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/220065/63039).

Answer (score 8):

### [`GraphicsGrid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsGrid.html)

For me, your `GraphicsGrid` doesn't have such issues with the spacings:

```
plots = Table[
  ListLinePlot[
   RandomReal[{-0.3, 0.3}, 10],
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, ColorData[112][i]},
   PlotRange -> {-0.3, 0.3},
   AxesStyle -> Black],
  {i, 3}, {j, 3}
  ]

Labeled[
 GraphicsGrid[
  plots,
  Spacings -> {0, 0},
  Frame -> None,
  AspectRatio -> 1
  ],
 {Pane["Too far out, and I need a label (centered) for each row"], 
  "Fine!", "This is fine, except I need a label (centered) for each \
column"},
 {Left, Bottom, Top},
 RotateLabel -> True,
 LabelStyle -> 
  Directive[Bold, FontFamily -> "Consolas", FontSize -> 16]
 ]
```

[image]

(this is using version 11.3 or 12.0 on Windows)

Now, to add the column/row-wise labels, you can use `Labeled` on the individual plots:

```
plots = Table[
  If[i == 1,
       Labeled[#, Row@{"Row ", j}, Top],
       #
       ] &@If[j == 1,
      Labeled[#, Row@{"Column ", i}, Left, RotateLabel -> True],
      #
      ] &@ListLinePlot[
    RandomReal[{-0.3, 0.3}, 10],
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, ColorData[112][i]},
    PlotRange -> {-0.3, 0.3},
    AxesStyle -> Black],
  {i, 3}, {j, 3}
  ]

Labeled[
 GraphicsGrid[
  plots,
  Spacings -> {0, 0},
  Frame -> None,
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  ImageSize -> 600
  ],
 {Pane["Too far out, and I need a label (centered) for each row"], 
  "Fine!", "This is fine, except I need a label (centered) for each \
column"},
 {Left, Bottom, Top},
 RotateLabel -> True,
 LabelStyle -> 
  Directive[Bold, FontFamily -> "Consolas", FontSize -> 16]
 ]
```

[image]

### [`ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid)

Alternatively, you could use [`ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid) together with `FrameLabel` on the individual plots and the entire plot-grid to get your labels:

```
plots = Table[
  ListLinePlot[
   RandomReal[{-0.3, 0.3}, 10],
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, ColorData[112][i]},
   PlotRange -> {-0.3, 0.3},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameStyle -> Black,
   FrameLabel -> {{Row@{"Row ", i}, None}, {None, Row@{"Column ", j}}},
   Axes -> True
   ],
  {i, 3}, {j, 3}
  ]
```

[image]

```
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][
 plots,
 FrameLabel -> {{Pane[
     "Too far out, and I need a label (centered) for each row"], 
    None}, {"Fine!", 
    "This is fine, except I need a label (centered) for each column"}},
 Spacings -> 10,
 ImageSize -> 700,
 "ShowFrameLabels" -> Automatic,
 FrameStyle -> 
  Directive[Black, Bold, FontFamily -> "Consolas", FontSize -> 16],
 AspectRatio -> 1
 ]
```

[image]

Note how the inner labels are automatically hidden, together with the tick labels. If you want all of the tick labels, use `"ShowFrameLabels"->Full`: (note that this requires hiding the `FrameLabel`s manually)

```
plots = Table[
  ListLinePlot[
   RandomReal[{-0.3, 0.3}, 10],
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, ColorData[112][i]},
   PlotRange -> {-0.3, 0.3},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameStyle -> Black,
   FrameLabel -> {{If[j == 1, Row@{"Row ", i}, None], None}, {None, 
      If[i == 1, Row@{"Column ", j}, None]}},
   Axes -> True
   ],
  {i, 3}, {j, 3}
  ]

ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][
 plots,
 FrameLabel -> {{Pane[
     "Too far out, and I need a label (centered) for each row"], 
    None}, {"Fine!", 
    "This is fine, except I need a label (centered) for each column"}},
 Spacings -> 30,
 ImageSize -> 700,
 "ShowFrameLabels" -> Full,
 FrameStyle -> 
  Directive[Black, Bold, FontFamily -> "Consolas", FontSize -> 16],
 AspectRatio -> 1
 ]
```

[image]

### Alignment issues

Something similar can of course also be achieved using `GraphicsGrid`. Note that `GraphicsGrid` will not properly align the individual plots in versions before 12.0 or when the plots are `Labeled`:

```
plots2 = Table[
  If[i == 1,
       Labeled[#, Row@{"Row ", j}, Top],
       #
       ] &@If[j == 1,
      Labeled[#, Row@{"Column ", i}, Left, RotateLabel -> True],
      #
      ] &@ListLinePlot[
    RandomReal[{-0.05, 0.3}, 10],
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, ColorData[112][i]},
    (*PlotRange\[Rule]{-0.3,0.3},*)
    AxesStyle -> Black,
    Frame -> True],
  {i, 3}, {j, 3}
  ]

Labeled[
 GraphicsGrid[
  plots2,
  Spacings -> {0, 0},
  Frame -> None,
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  ImageSize -> 600
  ],
 {Pane["Too far out, and I need a label (centered) for each row"], 
  "Fine!", "This is fine, except I need a label (centered) for each \
column"},
 {Left, Bottom, Top},
 RotateLabel -> True,
 LabelStyle -> 
  Directive[Bold, FontFamily -> "Consolas", FontSize -> 16]
 ]
```

[image]

This issue is only visible if the `ImagePadding` is not the same for all plots, as is e.g. the case when the plot ranges are not all the same. `ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]` will always align the plots properly, but is only available starting from version 11.3 (unless you manually copy the definition somewhere).

Answer (score 6):

`Grid` should do. Study docs on it for advanced options (`Alignment`, etc.). Small part for plot definitions (it is always better to provide your own complete code, even a toy sample, so people do not have to make it up and can see important details of your case):

```
data=RandomReal[{-1,1},{9,10}];
plots=Partition[ListLinePlot[Sort[#],PlotTheme->"Business"]&/@data,3];
```

And something like this:

```
{{"","COLUMN1","COLUMN2","COLUMN3"}}~Join~Transpose[{Rotate[#,Pi/2]&/@
{"ROW1","ROW2","ROW3"}}~Join~Transpose[plots]]//Grid
```

[image]

Comment: Note that `Grid` will not properly align the plots if their `ImagePadding` is inconsistent. `GraphicsGrid` does this properly in versions above 12.0. Of course, this is only an issue if the plot ranges are not all the same (and for `GraphicsGrid` the alignment also breaks down as soon as you wrap the plots with `Labeled` or similar).